# Docker PHP 8.2 fpm alpine will not install 8.2 PHP

Tags: php, linux, windows, docker, docker-compose

I must admit I am ready to bang my head against a wall. I have been working on this for days, reading articles and trying every which way to get docker to install a PHP 8.2 FMP alpine Container with no luck.

Right now, I already have a working container running with a project with 7.2-fpm-alpine. I did not set this up.

The funny thing is it runs on the php.ini in my XAMPP, which has version 7.4 PHP. I have several other projects in XAMPP I can not remove currently.

The new project requires me to work with laravel9 and PHP 8.2. The first issue I had was with pecl xdebug. I think I got it figured out! But no matter what I do, it will not upgrade the PHP in the container. It will always grab the XAMPP php.ini and stay with version 7.4.

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine3.17

RUN apk update

# Pull in nproc:
RUN apk add --no-cache coreutils

# Required for bandwidth graphs:
RUN apk add --no-cache net-snmp-tools

# Install the linux-headers package:
RUN apk add --update linux-headers

# ZIP:
RUN apk add --no-cache libzip-dev zlib-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip 
#--with-libzip
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" zip

# GMP:
RUN apk add --no-cache gmp-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gmp
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" gmp

# GD:
RUN apk add --no-cache libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" gd

# MYSQL PDO DRIVER:
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j "$(nproc)" pdo_mysql

# XDEBUG:
RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS
RUN apk add php81-pecl-xdebug
RUN apk add --update linux-headers
#RUN MAKEFLAGS="-j $(nproc)" pecl install xdebug
#RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Move php-fpm off of xdebug's port:
RUN sed -i 's/9000/9003/' /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

RUN echo 'clear_env = no' >> /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf

COPY . /var/www/studio

WORKDIR /var/www/studio

RUN php contrib/composer-installer \
  --2                              \
  --filename composer              \
  --install-dir /usr/local/bin

RUN addgroup -S art
RUN adduser -G art -S art

RUN chown -R art /var/www/studio
RUN chgrp -R art /var/www/studio

USER art

RUN composer --no-interaction --profile -vvv install
RUN composer check-platform-reqs
#RUN php artisan passport:keys

USER root

# Cleanup
RUN rm -f /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN rm -f /usr/src/php.tar.xz
RUN rm -f /usr/src/php.tar.xz.asc
RUN rm -rf contrib
RUN rm -rf /home/art/.composer

USER art
```

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.4.20 (cli) (built: Jun  1 2021 20:31:10) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

If I go to `/usr/local/etc/`, it is empty no `php` directory or `php.d` is found anywhere.

I am at a loss here.

```
version: "3.8"

x-env: &env
  APP_DEBUG_FILE: php://stdout
  DB_HOST: db
  DB_PORT: 3306
  DB_DATABASE: artdb
  DB_USERNAME: local
  DB_PASSWORD: local
x-php: &php
  init: true
x-studio: &studio
  <<: *php
  environment: << *env
x-tasks: &tasks
  <<: *php
  environment:
    <<: *env
    APP_ALERT_LOG: php://stdout
    APP_CONFTOOL_LOG: php://stdout
    APP_REPORT_LOG: php://stdout
services:
  studio:
    <<: *php
    build:
      context: art/studio
      dockerfile: contrib/localhost-fpm.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      <<: *env
    volumes:
      - ./art/studio:/var/www/studio
    # Expose xdebug's port:
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
  db:
    image: mariadb:10
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=local
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=local
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=local
    volumes:
      - ./data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    user: mysql
  nginx-studio:
    build:
      context: art/studio
      dockerfile: contrib/localhost-nginx.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - studio
```

Comment: What commands are you using? Did you rebuild / retag / and so, on the container?

Comment: ...and are you running those commands on the host (with a `C:\xampp\...` Windows-style path) or in a container (which I'd expect to have a Linux `/opt` or `/usr` path)?

Comment: I am new to all this, so explain this a little bit better to me.  Whatever I am doing, I am doing it wrong. Are there any commands I can run to find out the information to your question, or what do I need to look for in the code to answer all of them?  I can tell you that the code I am running is a git branch I got to start this project.  In it was all the setup of the Yaml and Docker files. `docker-compose -f docker-compose-localhost.yml build --no-cache` and `docker-compose -f docker-compose-localhost.yml up` Is what I use for the dockerization.

Comment: Added .yaml file to my first post for more information. Hope that will be helpful.

Comment: Try using the `--force-recreate` option, it will stop and recreate all your containers  - `docker-compose -f docker-compose-localhost.yml up --build --force-recreate`.

Comment: @VoidZA Gave it a try, PHP version is still 7.4.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am running the commands in `/c/Users/name/Docker/` I do have access to the Ubuntu Window Subsystem where there is a `/opt` and `/usr`

Comment: ...on the host system?  Nothing in this Dockerfile will have any effect there.

Answer (score 2):

So I stand corrected. It turns out I am wrong about Docker, and the error is on me. After starting this conversation, I started to investigate the Ubuntu interface. Looking at the running container and checking the PHP version ( which I should have done from the start), it showed as PHP 8.2.

I still have a lot to learn about this. Thank you to everyone that was helping.